# Apply gtk theme for Navicat lite in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: windows, gtk, themes, ubuntu-11.04, navicat

I downloaded Navicat Lite for Linux [here](https://www.navicat.com/en/download/navicat-for-mysql). It works so good except the ugly Windows-like theme. How can I apply my current gtk theme for it?

Note: The package I downloaded contains "wine" and "wine_old" folder and I didn't install WINE yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't have WINE applications look native on linux neither with QT or GTK+ (the standard toolkits for KDE and Gnome respectively) as WINE emulates the Win32 GUI directly to the XServer libraries so there is no way that WINE can "talk" to these toolkits, however, you can kinda use the colors.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/make-wine-applications-look-like-your.html), it has instructions on how to get the colors from your GTK theme to the Wine configuration, good luck!